# Rename Multiple workbook without opening that

Tags: excel, vba, rename

I have some workbook in folder and i want to change their name without opening them.

By some function i have picks their old name and added their new name in excel cell. example

AA1 - \ABC\Working File\2020-07-17.xlsx
AB 1 - \ABC\Working File\New_2020-07-17.xlsx

and so one till the blank row

can you please help me do the same.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the Name function in VBA

```
Sub Rename()
    For r = 1 To 1000  'each row, use for to prevent endless loop
        If (Sheets(1).Range("AA" + CStr(r)).Cells(1).Value) = "" Then Exit For
        'rename file
        Name Sheets(1).Range("AA" + CStr(r)).Cells(1).Value As Sheets(1).Range("AB" + CStr(r)).Cells(1).Value
    Next
End Sub
```